# Question about word/discourse similarity analysis

Tags: probability, randomness, latent-semantic-analysis

Question about a investigative journalistic proof involving LDA and prior along with general probability distribution model for an unusual type of problem.

Basically I have an email I wrote to a stranger who instead of replying or attributing to my two-to-three paragraphs of text (~ 75-100 words) he or she reposted similar (in idea somewhat in language) text on Wikipedia 12 hours later on an article that had existed for two years nearly enduring nearly no topic or subtopic emergences in that span until coincidentally hours after my email.

So I am wondering 1. How does one determine the similarity of text in the Wikipedia vs email text? 2. How would one determine the probability of this text being random vs non-random i.e. corelated or coauthored.

Thank you,
- Peter

Comment: This problem is not unusual, because independent solutions to a problem--and even encyclopedia entries--naturally tend to use similar language and similar ideas. With the limited data described in your question it's likely little can be done to demonstrate anything. However, if you had a corpus of posts by that stranger along with a representative set of your own posts, much can be done to address your concern. A seminal work in this area is Mosteller & Wallace, [*Inference and Disputed Authorship: The Federalist* (1964).](http://www.jstor.org/stable/202633?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: Thank you, while that work is older ('64) and unavailable for free I happened upon this modern solution to the inference problem. "The Disputed Federalist Papers: SVM Feature Selection via Concave Minimization" http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~gfung/federalist.pdf

Comment: It is well worth obtaining and studying the original.  Mosteller and Wallace wrote a (very readable) book with a similar title.  The "modern solution" could be superior--I haven't seen it--but I doubt it would provide the same deep and brilliant analysis of the original.

Comment: In my case this is not so much about which of x people wrote y but more about the statistical improbability that all these unique topical ideas appeared organized as such 12 hours after my email as a major statistical editorial anomaly too in the history of the article. And I mean major spike, like 1,200 chars, whereas the average edit over the last 10 years has been around 1-400 chars.  So while I hadn't / haven't edited Wikipedia to provide that corpus this user has edited 5 other places unrelated, and of course there's the entire daily editorial history of the article itself spanning years.

Comment: I'm probably more curious about showing how statistically unlikely it is that the edit was random in time not so much particular authorship but perhaps they'd used similar methods? And there must be a way of showing or indicating strong likelihood of similarity between text that is over 1,000 chars appearing so close together in time while most other days were largely silent without much discourse.

Comment: .. and also not so much proving whether or not I was the author of the text but showing that not only is it unlikely in time to have occurred randomly and that there is a substantial _similarity_ to the texts which is what NLP & neural networks excel at more than the intense methods laid out in The Federalist deconstruction. Fascinating area and similar indeed but critically different too.

Comment: I believe that what you ask for is impossible to obtain, because these events are described *post hoc*. The situation is not unlike observing the pattern HTHHTHHTTH of ten coin flips, noting that it represents 3^6=729 in binary (with H=1, T=0) and asking "what is the chance I could have flipped a perfect sixth power of an odd prime?" The uniquely defensible answer is "100%, because you are merely describing what has actually happened." Any other solution would be speculative and cannot validly be addressed with probability calculations.